# How to stop others posting on my Facebook Page Timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I do not want others to post on my Facebook Page. How to stop it?

Comment: Interestingly, I have the opposite problem. I've already enabled the settings "Allow visitors to the Page to publish posts" and "Allow photo and video posts", but visitors have recently stopped seeing the textarea where they'd been allowed to write a post to my page. I wonder if there is a recent FB bug.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily Stop Others From Posting on Facebook Wall on Web by following below mentioned points:

1. Launch www.facebook.com on your web browser.
2. Log in with your id & password.
3. Click on the inverted cone located on the right of upper menu → Click Settings.
4. Click on Timeline and Tagging from the left navigation.
5. Click on Edit next to “Who can post on your timeline?”
6. A drop-down menu will appear with two options: Friends and Only Me.
7. Click on Only Me.
8. Close the option from the right side.

That's all!!

If you are an iPhone user check the reference link to Stop Others from Posting on Your Facebook Timeline on iPhone.

Reference:
http://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-stop-others-from-posting-on-your-facebook-timeline-on-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

Go to your page's Admin Panel.  From the **Edit Page** menu, choose **Edit Settings**.

There, you will see an item named **Posting Ability**, which is apparently current set to "*Anyone can post to my page timeline*".  Click the corresponding **Edit** link, and uncheck the relevant boxes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the [Facebook Help Centre](https://www.facebook.com/help/356113237741414) (2017):

> You'll need to be an [admin](https://www.facebook.com/help/289207354498410?helpref=faq_content) to control what visitors can post on your Page. If you allow visitors to publish on your Page, their posts can appear in the **Visitor Posts** section on the right side of your Page. If you allow photo and video posts, posts by others can also appear in the **Photos** and **Videos** sections of your Page.
>
> To allow or disable posts by other people:
>
> 1. Click **Settings** at the top of your Page.
> 2. From **General**, click **Visitor Posts**.
> 3. Select **Allow visitors to the Page to publish posts** or **Disable posts by other people on the Page**. If you allow visitors to publish posts, you can choose to:
>
>    - Allow photo and video posts
>    - Review posts by other people before they're published to the Page
> 4. Click **Save Changes**.
>
> If you choose to review posts, posts by others will be hidden from your Page by default. To approve a post, go to the **Posts by Others** section of your Page's [activity log](https://www.facebook.com/help/229085757185936?helpref=faq_content), click 0(circle symbol) next to the post and select **Allowed on Page**.
>
> Keep in mind that you can't disable comments on your Page's posts, but you can [hide or delete individual comments](https://www.facebook.com/help/297845860255949?helpref=faq_content). You can also proactively moderate comments and posts by visitors by [blocking words and turning on the profanity filter](https://www.facebook.com/help/131671940241729?helpref=faq_content) for your Page.

Comment: But above does not work on mobile browser. There is no option of " visitors posts" if you check settings via Chrome browser in mobile phone